# vJS or jQuery -- set / get simplified selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I'm having trouble getting and setting the "simplified" selected value of a select using jquery or vanilla js. i.e. `<option value="foo" selected>` vs. `<option value="foo" selected="selected">`.

Below only works if the option is selected like below, but all the programmatic ways to set the value of a select option I have tried result in `<option value="value" selected="selected">`. I need to set and get the simplified `selected`.

```
const sortBySelect = document.getElementById('sortBy');
let currVal = sortBySelect[sortBySelect.selectedIndex].value; 
console.log(currVal);

<select id="sortBy">
  <option value="title" selected>Title</option>
  <option value="date">Date</option>
  <option value="name">Name</option>
</select>
```

I've tried these and all the permutations I could find on Stack:

```
$(`#sortBy option[value='${storageValue}']`).attr('selected', true);
$(`#sortBy option[value='${storageValue}']`).prop('selected', "selected");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `attr()` or `prop()` functions, just directly set the `select` value by using the `val()` function

```
$('#sortBy').val('${storageValue}');
```